# How to create a loop in a script PHP?

Tags: php

I'm using this script.

```
<?php
function handle_url($url){
    $file = 'result.txt';
    $long_url = urlencode($url);
    $api_token = '0123456789';
    $api_url = "https://mywebsite.com/api?api={$api_token}&url={$long_url}";
    $result = file_get_contents($api_url);
    if( $result ){
        echo $result;
    }
    file_put_contents($file, $long_url . PHP_EOL, FILE_APPEND);
    file_put_contents($file, $result . PHP_EOL, FILE_APPEND);
    fclose($file);
    sleep(1);
}

$file = fopen('mylink.txt', 'r');
if ($file){
    while (!feof($file)) {
        handle_url(fgets($file));
    }
    fclose($file);
}
?>
```

The file **mylink.txt** contains a list of links.

The script should go through the entire list, but in reality only the first line is executed.

Why is there no cycle?

Please help me fix the script.

Comment: The answer by [MajidGh](https://stackoverflow.com/users/2707278/majidgh), that solved your problem, was deleted by [blackgreen](https://stackoverflow.com/users/4108803/blackgreen), a moderator here. I don't know why. Anyway, removing the `fclose($file);` line in your function solved it. Next time try to [switch on error reporting](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1053424/how-do-i-get-php-errors-to-display), or look in log files. That way you can solve these kind of problems yourself.

Comment: Well, I looked a bit into it, and I can think of 2 reasons why the answer was deleted: 1. It points out the wrong reason, but happens to mention the solution as well. 2. It was generated by AI. I don't think the latter is the case, so it must be the first.

Answer (score 0):

You need to remove the following line from your function **handle_url**.

```
fclose($file);
```

This is, because `$file` does not contain a file handle resource returned by [fopen()](https://www.php.net/manual/de/function.fopen.php), but just a string containing the file name `result.txt`. Only file handles can be closed with [fclose()](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.fclose.php).